# Cannot remotely connect to the MS SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I already enabled remote access in the server, but still, I cannot remotely connect to the server.
TCP/IP, namedpipes and shared is also enabled.

Attached is the error message from my navicat:
[image]

I have already enabled remote access in the MS SQL Management Studio and also the namedpipes and TCP/IP in the SQL Configuration Manager. But still, I cannot connect remotely to the server using my Navicat app using the SQL server authentication.

Comment: SQL Server Express normally only listens on localhost/127.0.0.1 by default. When reconfiguring its Server Protocols in SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager did you enable any other IP addresses for listening? Did you also restart the SQL Server Express instance after reconfiguring it? If you're using an instance name in your connection string did you also restart the SQL Browser service?